# How may I quickly rollback the state to just a few moments ago?

Tags: .net, sql-server, bdd

I am trying to take a .NET stack and implement scripted BDD/Cucumber using a separate platform(node.js - our new stack). I would like to reset the database to a starting point after each Cucumber scenario, but not restore the whole database every time.

Hence, my desired procedure would look like:

- launch .NET stack
- take some snapshot of the database or put it in some transaction mode
- launch node.js test suite
- run a scenario
- reset/rollback the SQL server database
- run another scenario

...etc.

I have a node module at my disposal which will allow me to issue SQL commands to the SQL Server.

Comment: Can your server handle [Database Snapshots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, it can.

Comment: If your database is small-ish, a scripted database restore routine can complete in seconds. I use this method when testing as ETL routine and I constantly rollback to the base db.

Comment: I have never used BDD so I can't tell you how to set it up, but I would say make a snapshot at the before the test then restore from the snapshot at the start of each test. After all tests finish delete the snapshot. If you figure out how to do it write up an answer so other people in the future can share in what you learned.